# Copy all data from ArrayList that updated his data at each iteration

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `List<String>` in a `for` that change its data at each iteration. I want to return an `ArrayList` with all the data which were stored in the list `wordForms`.

```
List<String> wordForms = new ArrayList();
List<Synset> synsetsNoun = wordnet.getNounSynsetsOf(category);

for (Synset synset : synsetsNoun) {
    wordForms = WordNetSynset.getWordFormsOf(synset);
    System.out.println("\ts: " + wordForms);
}
```

In the first iteration, `wordForm` has 5 elements, the second iteration it has 3 elements and so on.

I want to return an `ArrayList` with **all that elements**, how can I do that?

---

As an example suppose that I get an `ArrayList<String>` like

```
Element1
Element2
```

in the first iteration, then

```
Element3
Element4
Element5
```

in the second iteration, and so on.

The desired output then would be an `ArrayList<String>` containing **all** those elements:

```
Element1
Element2
Element3
Element4
Element5
```

Comment: For starters, you're reassigning it at every iteration...meaning only the last call will be effective.

Comment: Can you give us an example input, the current output for this example and the desired output? Currently it's not that easy to get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Just as a side-note, you shouldn't create the `ArrayList` with **raw-types** like `new ArrayList()`. Instead use `new ArrayList<String>()` or the **diamond-operator** `new ArrayList<>()` as the compiler already knows the type because of the `List<String> wordForms = ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are **reassigning** your `wordForms` variable **every iteration**.

Instead of that you need to **add** the elements from each iteration. You do so by using the method `ArrayList#add` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-)).

However currently you are fetching **collections of elements** to add (`ArrayList<String>`). You can now either iterate all of those elements and add them individually to your `wordForms` or use the designated method `ArrayList#addAll` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-)) which does the same behind the scenes.

```
for (Synset synset : synsetsNoun) {
    // Fetch the elements to add
    ArrayList<String> elementsToAdd = WordNetSynset.getWordFormsOf(synset);

    // Add the elements to the list
    wordForms.addAll(elementsToAdd);
}

// Print the contents
System.out.println("\ts: " + wordForms);
```

---

Or if you want to try this in **functional style** in **Java 8**:

```
List<String> wordForms = synsetsNoun.stream()           // Synsets
    .map(WordNetSynset::getWordFormsOf)                 // Lists of wordForms
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)                        // WordForms
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));  // Collect to ArrayList

// Print the contents
System.out.println("\ts: " + wordForms);
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
List<String> wordForms = new ArrayList();
List<Synset> synsetsNoun = wordnet.getNounSynsetsOf(category);

for (Synset synset : synsetsNoun) {
    wordForms.add(WordNetSynset.getWordFormsOf(synset));
}

System.out.println("\ts: " + wordForms);
```

This is assuming your `getWordFormsOf(...)` method returns a String object. If so, this snippet of code will be adding that String into your ArrayList.

In the other hand if your `getWordFormsOf` method returns a List of String objects you might use:

`for (Synset synset : synsetsNoun) {
        wordForms.addAll(WordNetSynset.getWordFormsOf(synset));
    }`

Comment: Can you explain what you have changed and why it solves the issue?

Comment: @Zabuza, assuming the `getWordFormsOf` returns `String` I only add that String to the ArrayList.

Comment: You may include that **in your answer** to improve its quality. However I think the method returns a whole collection of elements `ArrayList<String>`. Otherwise OP wouldn't be able to reassign `wordForms` with it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Zabuza

Comment: Zabusa was right, getWordFormsOf return an ArrayList<String>. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 you can use the Stream for this. As per your given code `WordNetSynset.getWordFormsOf(synset)` will return `List<String>`.
So you can replace the line `wordForms = WordNetSynset.getWordFormsOf(synset)` with below line.

```
List<String> wordForms = new ArrayList();
List<Synset> synsetsNoun = wordnet.getNounSynsetsOf(category);

for (Synset synset : synsetsNoun) {
    wordForms = Stream.concat(wordForms.stream(), WordNetSynset.getWordFormsOf(synset).stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
System.out.println("\ts: " + wordForms);
```

Also if you want to remove the duplicates from your wordForms list you can add `.distinct()` function to your Stream.

Comment: Thanks! I will use Stream to add distinct() function. It worked fine.

Comment: I don't see the pros in using `Stream` only for the later half. You could use it for the whole process, using a `Stream` on `synsetsNoun`, then **mapping** to `WordNetSynset::getWordFormsOf`, then **flat-mapping** to their `Stream` and finally **collecting**. Please note that your current way of collecting does not ensure an `ArrayList` in the end (just in case OP has a problem with that).

Comment: @Zabuza your are correct Im just pointed out the main thing which is the way to concatenation of the lists using Stream.